# ¿Como hago el método de burbujeo en un vector? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero ordenar de menor a mayor, o de mayor a menor un vector. Pensaba en hacerlo con el método de burbujeo, pero no se como implementarlo en mi código html. Acá esta el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intercambiar el mayor por el menor. Vectores.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viejo=[1,2,7,5,6,3,4];
        var nuevo=[];
        var pos_nuevo=0;
        for(var pos_viejo=(viejo.length-1);pos_viejo>=0;pos_viejo--){
            nuevo[pos_nuevo]=viejo[pos_viejo];
            pos_nuevo++;
        }
        document.write(nuevo);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo al pseudocódigo del algoritmo: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja

Comment: Hola necesitas hacer este metodo para alguna tarea en especifico?. Te pregunto porque ya existen metodos que realizan este tipo de cosas tienes el metodo `sort()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) y una vez ordenado puedes aplicarle `reverse()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 1):

Ordenar un array en Javascript es una tarea que ya viene implementada, sólo requiere de que le indiques con una función cómo se comparan los elementos:

```js
let array = [10, 2, 13, 4, 25, 16, 7];

function compara(a,b) {
  return a-b; // >0 indica que a es mayor, <0 indica que b es mayor, 0 que son iguales
}

function compara2(a,b) {
  return b-a;
}

console.log(array.sort(compara).toString());

console.log(array.sort(compara2).toString());
```